# Restore Default Super Key Behavior (xkbmap)

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, super-key

`setxkbmap` has always been a healthy bit of black magic as far as I'm concerned. I recently installed [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/). When I run the command `dyalog`, it globally changes my keyboard configuration to APL mode, which effectively disables my ability to use the Super key for anything else. Now, this is actually quite nice *while* I'm using APL. But then when I close the process, I'm left with a nigh-worthless Super key that can't do any of its usual functions, like switch between windows or open the Activities menu. So my question is, how do I change it back?

Specifically, here's the "normal" output of `setxkbmap -print`, on a fresh login.

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+us:2+inet(evdev)+capslock(ctrl_modifier)"};
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

(The caps lock/ctrl modifier is unrelated to this question, so feel free to ignore that)

When I run Dyalog, it changes my keyboard map, so `setxkbmap -print` becomes

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+apl(dyalog):2+us:3+inet(evdev)+group(win_switch)+capslock(ctrl_modifier)"    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

So what `setxkbmap` command(s) can I run to go from the second state back to the first one? I want to be able to get the default behavior of my Super key back, on demand.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, with Gnome 3.28.4 on X11, if any of that matters for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can use the output of `setxkbmap -print` for that,
but there are at least three other approaches to restore the default
keyboard state.

#### Option 0

Execute

```
xkbcomp "$DISPLAY" normal.xkb
```

while the keyboard is in its default state. [Xkbcomp](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xkbcomp.1.xhtml) creates `normal.xkb`
file, the keyboard's complete default keymap. After you are done with Dyalog,
the keyboard state can be easily restored with

```
xkbcomp normal.xkb "$DISPLAY"
```

#### Option 1

From [`man keyboard`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/keyboard-configuration/keyboard.5.en.html), for Debian based systems:

> ```
>  udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
> ```

#### Option 2

Retrieve from `/etc/default/keyboard` the relevant settings for
[the `setxkbmap` command](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Using_setxkbmap):

```
setxkbmap [-model xkb_model] [-layout xkb_layout] [-variant xkb_variant] [-option xkb_options]
```

For example, given this `/etc/default/keyboard`,

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

You would restore that default state with

```
setxkbmap -model 'pc105' -layout 'us' -option 'caps:escape,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp'
```

Comment: Excellent! For whatever reason, Option 1 had no effect for me. But Option 2 works a charm. Unfortunately, to get my caps/ctrl behavior back, I have to go into Gnome Tweaks and poke that setting as well, but I imagine I can figure out how to get around that with `XKBOPTIONS` now that I know where to look. Thanks!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Option 1 requires sudo/root and a Debian based system, maybe it was that. But so glad to hear Option 2 it works. I regard every solution on the arcane keyboard utilities a victory! Yes, you are probably able to do it if you set `XKBOPTIONS` appropriatedly, and then you put Gnome Tweaks aside. `man xkeyboard-config` contains the relevant info.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I have added one more (probably the most elegant, simple and reliable) option. You may want to try that

Answer (score -2):

What about using directly the APL keymap shipped with XKB?

Have a look into **/usr/share/X11/symbols/apl**, you can use it as a secondary layout.